# Eye of Gnome Python plugins won't autogen because check for PYGTK fails

Tags: pygtk

Presenting symptom: autogen disables the build of slideshowshuffle and pythonconsole, reporting "no python support."  Platform is Ubuntu 9.04, Jaunty Jackalope; Gnome 2.26.1.

Log extract:

```
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.3... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.6
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.6/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.6/site-packages
checking for PYGTK... no
configure: WARNING: Python not found, disabling python support
```

Evidence that both python and pygtk are installed:

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygtk
>>>
```

I note the capitalization of PYGTK, which is common for environment variables.  There is no PYGTK environment variable.

> Your search - "PYGTK environment
>   variable" - did not match any
>   documents.

A grep for PYGTK in the tree rooted from /usr/share/doc/python-gtk2-doc/html returned no rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing "python-gtk2-dev" package. You can make sure you have it with

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep pygtk-2.0
```

I think, the one you're using from python is "python-gtk2".